# Discord py background task does not send messages to all channels

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a bot that sends random messages to all servers and channels it is in at 60 sec intervals, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        for server in client.servers:
            for channel in server.channels:
                await client.send_message(channel, "Some message")
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('<my token>')
```

The above does not throw any errors. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are waiting a minute after each channel message.

Comment: I meant 60 sec intervals.

Comment: If you `except Exception as e` and print whatever exception you get, if any, that might help you see if there is a permissions error or some timeout or similar unknown issue.

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: The `asyncio.sleep` is outside of the loop, but you should still be seeing a few messages.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh My bad - I made a mistake copying the code onto stackoverflow. It still doesn’t return anything though - I suspect ‘server.channels’ does not return anything. What do you think?

Comment: All servers should have at least one channel.  Try adding some `print`s to see if you're even getting into the loop.

Comment: I just tested it with print statements - the background event is called, but `client.servers` doesn't return anything...

Comment: Did you try something like `print([server.name for server in client.servers])`? This may be a dumb question, but are you sure your bot is a member of at least one server?  Can you see it in the list of members when it comes online?

Comment: It finally worked! I used `client.get_all_servers()` and subsequently cycled through them. Thank you for your help! :)